# How do I get the new pets, Orby and Asmody?

Tags: across-the-obelisk

The patch a few days ago added two new pets.  We've played all the way through the game looking for them, but couldn't find either of them.  There's nothing in any of the guides or forum posts online.

How do you get these pets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No one had figured it out on the forums so I reverse engineered the game.  Spoilers ahead!

---

### Orby

1. First we need some Obsideon Ingots. The only place to get those is at the crane in the red portal.
   [image: Red portal]
   If the crane is a rare (purple) event, you're guaranteed to get them after fighting the enemies.  If it's *not* a rare event, you have a *chance* of getting them if you choose "pull it up". Any other choice (including the character-specific ones!) will not get you the ingots.

   Unfortunately, you may need to run halfway through the game several times to get them :(
2. In Act IV, give the ingots to the blacksmith.
   [image: Act IV]

---

### Asmody

1. In Act 1, visit the "A Fun Game" node.  This is a rare node, so you will need to keep restarting until it appears.
   Ride down the river, then fight the enemies behind the waterfall to get the first word of the password.
   [image: Act 1]
2. In the red portal, visit "The Empty Camp" and search for the demon summoning book.
   [image: Red Portal]
3. In Act IV (lower level), visit the library and search for the demon summoning book.
   [image: Act IV]
4. In Act IV (upper level), visit the *magic circle* (lower path) and enter the code to summon the demon.
   [image: Act IV 2]
   *(thanks to dave_d for the image)*

Comment: Game seed EAHKA82 will allow you to unlock both pets in one run.

Comment: Gameseed for #1.0.1d with both events: "X8AWY6T". Btw the event "Fun Games" is now called differently but on the same location.

Comment: You can also get guaranteed Obsidian Ingots from the Forge location in the Black Forge.